# Convert NetworkX heterogeneous Multigraph into PyTorch Geometric data

Tags: pytorch, networkx, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network, gnn

I have a heterogeneous graph with different node types and attributes stored as NetworkX Multigraph. I want to train a GNN model on this graph, therefore I need to convert it into PyTorch Geometric datatype.

I tried built-in function

```
from torch_geometric.utils.convert import from_networkx
data_PyG = from_networkx(G)
```

But it only works if G is `networkx.Graph` or `networkx.DiGraph` with the same set of attributes.
Is there a way to automatically convert `nx.Multigraph` into `HeteroData()`?